# jquery only allow input float number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i'm making some input mask that allows only float number. But current problem is I can't check if multiple dots entered. Can you check those dots and prevent it for me?

Live Code: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/VRa6n/

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which != 46 && (event.which < 47 || event.which > 59))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ((event.which == 46) && ($(this).indexOf('.') != -1)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a regex `/^\d+\.\d+$/` or something like that.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check for the period in the same statement.

Also, you need to use the `val` method to get the value of the element.

Also, you want to check for the interval 48 to 57, not 47 to 59, otherwise you will also allow `/`, `:` and `;`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.float-number').keypress(function(event) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
      <body>
        Enter Number:
        <input type="text" name="number" value="" class="float-number">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but what about case if first symbol is dot?

Comment: @user2167382: That is only a problem if you specify that it's not allowed. Parsing a string like `'.42'` to a floating point number works just fine. The zero before the period is optional is scientific notation (as long as there are digits after the period of course).

Comment: @RohitSutharYiiExpert: You can add ` && event.which != 8` in the condition to fix that.

Comment: @Guffa thanks, also what about in copy-paste situation??

Comment: @RohitSutharYiiExpert: The keys for that would also have specific key codes, but I think that you should check for what characters you want to disallow rather than which to allow.

Comment: this is now allowing to delete by back space after adding some thing in input box.

Comment: @Naveen: See the comments by RohitSutharYiiExpert above.

Comment: Why is jquery checks necessary considering that <input type=number> guarantees it's a float?

Answer (score 23):

I think you guys have missed the left right arrows, delete and backspace keys.

```
 $('.number').keypress(function(event) {

     if(event.which == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46) 
          return true;

     else if((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))
          event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Your else if condition is wrong, it allows several dots to enter. It should be like `if(event.which == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
          event.preventDefault();
      } `

Comment: It also allows `% and '`

Comment: It also allows % and '

Answer (score 6):

I think everybody forgot the case of pasting text with the mouse, in which you can't detect the keystrokes, because there's none. Here's another approach I have been working on.

```
// only integer or float numbers (with precision limit)
// example element: <input type="text" value="" class="number" name="number" id="number" placeholder="enter number" />

$('.number').on('keydown keypress keyup paste input', function () {

    // allows 123. or .123 which are fine for entering on a MySQL decimal() or float() field
    // if more than one dot is detected then erase (or slice) the string till we detect just one dot
    // this is likely the case of a paste with the right click mouse button and then a paste (probably others too), the other situations are handled with keydown, keypress, keyup, etc

    while ( ($(this).val().split(".").length - 1) > 1 ) {

        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));

        if ( ($(this).val().split(".").length - 1) > 1 ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // replace any character that's not a digit or a dot

    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));

    // now cut the string with the allowed number for the integer and float parts
    // integer part controlled with the int_num_allow variable
    // float (or decimal) part controlled with the float_num_allow variable

    var int_num_allow = 3;
    var float_num_allow = 1;

    var iof = $(this).val().indexOf(".");

    if ( iof != -1 ) {

        // this case is a mouse paste (probably also other events) with more numbers before the dot than is allowed
        // the number can't be "sanitized" because we can't "cut" the integer part, so we just empty the element and optionally change the placeholder attribute to something meaningful

        if ( $(this).val().substring(0, iof).length > int_num_allow ) {
            $(this).val('');
            // you can remove the placeholder modification if you like
            $(this).attr('placeholder', 'invalid number');
        }

        // cut the decimal part

        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, iof + float_num_allow + 1));

    } else {

        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, int_num_allow));

    }

    return true;

});
```

Comment: Very good and very easy. You just change your regex and will work for other validations as well. Great work buddy.

Answer (score 6):

Good for integer and float values. Plus, copy/paste clipboard event.

```js
var el = $('input[name="numeric"]');
el.prop("autocomplete",false); // remove autocomplete (optional)
el.on('keydown',function(e){
 var allowedKeyCodesArr = [9,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,8,37,39,109,189,46,110,190];  // allowed keys
 if($.inArray(e.keyCode,allowedKeyCodesArr) === -1 && (e.keyCode != 17 && e.keyCode != 86)){  // if event key is not in array and its not Ctrl+V (paste) return false;
  e.preventDefault();
 } else if($.trim($(this).val()).indexOf('.') > -1 && $.inArray(e.keyCode,[110,190]) != -1){  // if float decimal exists and key is not backspace return fasle;
  e.preventDefault();
 } else {
  return true;
 };  
}).on('paste',function(e){  // on paste
 var pastedTxt = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text').replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');  // get event text and filter out letter characters
 if($.isNumeric(pastedTxt)){  // if filtered value is numeric
  e.originalEvent.target.value = pastedTxt;
  e.preventDefault();
 } else {  // else 
  e.originalEvent.target.value = ""; // replace input with blank (optional)
  e.preventDefault();  // retur false
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="numeric" value="" placeholder="insert value">
```

**[2017-10-31]** Vanilla.js

```js
let el = document.querySelector('input[name="numeric"]');
el.addEventListener('keypress',(event) => {
  let k = event.key,
      t = isNaN(k),
      sc = ['Backspace'].indexOf(k) === -1,
      d = k === '.',dV = el.value.indexOf('.') > -1,
      m = k === '-',mV = el.value.length > 0;

      if((t && sc) && ((d && dV) || (m && dV) || (m && mV) || ((t && !d) && (t && !m)))){event.preventDefault();}
},false);
el.addEventListener('paste',(event) => {
    if(event.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/html') > -1){
        if(isNaN(event.clipboardData.getData('text'))){event.preventDefault();}
    }
},false);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numeric">
```

Comment: Now it does :) . Just remove or add keyCodes in to the allowedKeyCodesArr var.

Comment: It does allow 3453. If numbers after decimal point are not entered.It should check on blur and should not allow.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems quite fine but overcomplicated.

First, it is `$(this).val().indexOf`, because you want to do something with the value.

Second, the `event.which == 46` check is inside an `if` clause that's only passed when `event.which != 46`, which can never be true.

I ended up with this which works: http://jsfiddle.net/VRa6n/3/.

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which < 46
    || event.which > 59) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } // prevent if not number/dot

    if(event.which == 46
    && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } // prevent if already dot
});
```

Comment: event.which for . is 190 on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="text"  onkeypress="return isFloatNumber(this,event)" />
```

Javascript

```
function isFloatNumber(item,evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode==46)
    {
        var regex = new RegExp(/\./g)
        var count = $(item).val().match(regex).length;
        if (count > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/4pfp3wne/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I found this way to do this,

```
$.validator.addMethod("currency", function (value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid amount");
```

https://gist.github.com/jonkemp/9094324

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function()
     {
        //Only number and one dot
        function onlyDecimal(element, decimals)
        {
            $(element).keypress(function(event)
            {
                num = $(this).val() ;
                num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num ;
                if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57))
                {
                    event.preventDefault();

                }
                if($(this).val() == parseFloat(num).toFixed(decimals))
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }

         onlyDecimal("#TextBox1", 3) ;



    });
```

Comment: Best solution so far - perhaps an option for beeping if incorrect input?

Comment: but what about case if first symbol is dot(if it is i can input more that number of decimals in function) and why i can't edit inputed decimal if i input 3 digits after point?

Answer (score 1):

One-more plugin, based on Carlos Castillo answer

https://github.com/nikita-vanyasin/jquery.numberfield.js

Adds method to jQuery object:

```
$('input.my_number_field').numberField(options);
```

where options is (you can pass any or no options):

```
{
    ints: 2, // digits count to the left from separator
    floats: 6, // digits count to the right from separator
    separator: "."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and allowing negative floats :

```
// Force floats in '.js_floats_only' inputs
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js_floats_only').each(function() {
        // Store starting value in data-value attribute.
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
    });
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.js_floats_only', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if ( val == '-' ) {
        // Allow starting with '-' symbol.
        return;
    } else {
        if ( isNaN(val) ) {
            // If value is not a number put back previous valid value.
            this.value = $(this).data('value');
        } else {
            // Value is valid, store it inside data-value attribute.
            $(this).data('value', val);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases and without hardcoding some html instructions would fit that pretty enough

```
<input type="number" step="0.01"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event){
            if($.browser.mozilla == true){
                  if (event.which == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 46){
                        return true;
                  }
            }
            if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
                });
```

This works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-textboxtype="numeric" />
<script>
    $(document).on('keydown', '[data-textboxtype="numeric"]', function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and . and -
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190, 109, 189]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return true;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Below Code  I am allowing only Digits and Dot symbol. 
>   
>   ASCII characters number starts in 47 and ends with 58 and dot value is 190.

```
   $("#Experince").keyup(function (event) {
        debugger

        if ((event.which > 47
            && event.which < 58) ||event.which== 190) {
             if ($("#Experince").val().length > 3) {

        }
        } // prevent if not number/dot
        else {
             $("#Experince").val($("#Experince").val().slice(0, -1))
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.number').on('keypress', function (event) {
    let text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) && (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Jquery Only Allow Input Float Number</h1>
    <input type="text" name="number" class="number" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```