# How can I get a number input element with a step motor to append a "0" to represent monetary vals?

Tags: jquery, html, input, floating-point, number-formatting

Thanks to help from Dave (so much for "Dave's not here") here: [Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5#19011861), I've got a floating point element, but when I set the stop motor to 0.05, it goes:

```
0.05
0.1
0.15
0.2
```

etc.

I want it to represent money, so that it goes:

```
0.05
0.10
0.15
0.20
```

Will I have to write jQuery to append this "0" on the blurring of the widget, or...???

Comment: So you want to have two digits after the point all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any means to format input value other than JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=number]')
.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var parts = this.value.split('.');

    // Integer number
    if (parts.length < 2) {
        this.value += '.00';
    }

    // Single digit after the point
    else if (parts[1].length < 2) {
        this.value += '0';
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kdUJm/