# How to show on 2 or more decimal places html form element input type="number" , whose value is like integer.For example how to 200 show like 200.00

Tags: php, html

For example.
$somevalue is php variable, come from database, and is $somevalue=200.00 . I would like that in form in

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="'.$somevalue.'">
```

$somevalue is show like 200.00 not like 200.

My code :

```
<?php
$somevalue=200;
$type_number='<input type="number" step="0.01" value="'.$somevalue.'">';
echo $type_number; 
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Number Input - Always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: The solution from before question not show value in 2 decimals if type="number" , and if step is something (exampl: 0.01)  when value is integer for example 200 , 100, 10, 55 etc.

Comment: cast to float and fix to two decimal place

Comment: If You think something like this in javascript  'y=parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)' and then change value in javascript , this not work becouse type="number" . $somevalue is again and beyond shown without decimals although for example y=200.00 . Where x is $somevalue=200

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

Because every browser is different you can do a little edit with jQuery:

```js
    $('input').each(function() {
      var help = $(this).val().split('.');
      if (help.length == 1) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '.00');
      } else if (help[1].length == 1) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '0');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="200">
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="200.11">
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="200.1">
```

Comment: Why downvoting? He is talking about Integer so there are ALWAYS a 0 after the dot

Comment: whats happened if   $somevalue = 200.1  or  2.99  ?

Comment: $somevalue is from database and can be evrything with 2 decimals or integer whotever. But should be shown with 2 decimals. For example value 200 like 200.00 , value 200.23   like 200.23. Evry Values whose have 2 decimals is shown good. But if values have more than 2 decimals is shown without decimals.

Comment: Okay, the question was unclear. I thought you have only integers and want to show them with a `.00` So you just want to display a number with two decimal inputs, even when its an integer

Comment: Yes. I have diferent $somevalue-s in database with 2 decimals and some are integers like 200.00 and some are for example 234.54 or 234.50 etc . I wold like this numbers in html form on <input type="number" step="0.01" value="$somevalue"> evry value show with 2 decimals. Now is case that when value is 200.00 is shown like 200 or 200.50 is shown like 200.5 . I d like to be shown lik 200.00 or 200.50   . Im not shure if it is anyway possible :)

Comment: added my answer, not it works in every browser the right way

Comment: a lots of code and Jquery is not required for this !  var num = 200;  var n = num.toFixed(2);  // output 200.00  ,  and its still remove zero

Comment: @CyC0der of course you can do it without jquery. But the algorithm is right.

Comment: i don't said its not right , when you wanna go to work! do you choose longer way ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use  [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
    <?php
         echo number_format('200', 2, '.', ',');
         // Output 200.00

        echo number_format('200.1', 2, '.', ',');
        //output 200.10


        echo number_format('20.21', 2, '.', ',');
        //output 20.21

      $somevalue=number_format($somevalue, 2, '.', ',');
      $type_number='<input type="number" step="0.01" value="'.$somevalue.'">';
       echo $type_number; 

    ?>
```

Comment: number_format is OK when You write echo and if You have form input type="text" Here I have input  type="number" .

Comment: do you know php language structure? thats ok with echo 
$somevalue =  number_format($somevalue, 2, '.', ',');

Comment: When I use this : 
<?php
$somevalue=300;
$somevalue=number_format($somevalue, 2, '.', ',');
echo "somevalue".$somevalue."<br>";
$type_number='<input type="number" step="0.01" value="'.$somevalue.'">';
echo $type_number; 
?>
and the result is:
somevalue=300.00
input show 300

Comment: i tested and see! its firefox problem its works on chrome ,  depends to the browser ability and you can't change it , if its important for you use Jquery Plugins like https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: In Chrome it's showing 300.00, but in Firefox 300. So it's browser specific.

Comment: Yes, I also  try in chrome and in chrome realy show  300,00

Answer (score 0):

you can use **sprintf()**

```html
 $type_number='<input type="number" step="0.01" value="'.sprintf('%2f',$somevalue).'">';
```