# what is the use of type = number allow to type 0123456789.Ee-+ even it returning invalid value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, integer

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.addMe="";
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">          
      <input type="number" ng-model="addMe">
      
    <p>{{addMe}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actually input `type = number` does not allow most of the special characters to enter. But it's only allowing to enter `+ and - and (Adding and subscription)`  even why it does not allowing to enter `/ and * (divide and multiply)`.

And also the input field value will be invalid while we entering  `- and +` in the input box

I am not sure this problem occurred from browser or Html because I got some details from this answer for  [**`0123456789.Ee-+` are all legal characters according to Chrome**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751682/2218635). But I have checked with this in IE 11 browser as well which is getting this same problem. So we have an idea about   [input type = number should allow - and + like `0123456789.Ee-+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in)  value But i don't know what is the use to allow this characters?

> *My main question is why the `type=number` allow to enter those character then why it's returning invalid value? if the input box returning invalid value then why it's allowing to type those charterers ?? What is the Use? **Use**?*

Comment: These are not symbols for adding and substraction in this case but indication wheter a number is below or above zero

Comment: Also if you enter (e) on textbox then it will also acceptable in number type text box.know more about e constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Comment: @sachin Then why it does not accept the negative value??

Comment: because a number can also be a negative or positive number to maintain (+) or (-) number there are min and max attribute available to restrict user input

Comment: @MartinSchneider Could you  please read my question clearly. I have linked that details in my question. please take a look at my main question.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I did read your Posting clearly, but you added the "My main question" part afterwards.

Comment: @MartinSchneider I clearly asked **what is the use to allow this characters** previously. But any way I hope now you can understand my question clearly.

Comment: I got it now and clarified clearly. Please check my answer. Thank you so much for your valuable time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it for why it is allowing those chars. here is the use of  `. e + -`

- `1e1 = 10// use of e or E`
- `1e+1 = 10// use of +`
- `1e-1 = 0.1// use of -`
- `1.1 = 1.1// use of .`

> So this is the reason for type=number is allowing to type those characters. And if we typing wrongly then only it's  will be return `invalid` value.

---

You can check those in below snippet for those values.

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.eorE=1e1;
  $scope.float=1.1;
  $scope.plus=1e+1;
  $scope.mins=1e-1;
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">          
      <input type="number" ng-model="eorE">
      <input type="number" ng-model="float">
      <input type="number" ng-model="plus">
      <input type="number" ng-model="mins">
      
    <p>{{addMe}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```