# Firefox: how to show number input value with decimal spaces

Tags: html, firefox, input

I am only having this issue on firefox, it works as expected on chrome.

If I have a number input with a value of "20.00" or 20.00 (as a string or number) it always shows 20 without the decimal spaces inside the input box.

I need the `type="number"` so avoid other inputs that aren't numbers because of internal calculations that are done after the input.

For example:

```html
<label>Input with number value as string</label>
<input type="number" value="20.00" step="0.01">

<br>

Input with number value as number
<input type="number" value=20.00 step="0.01">
```

How can I have the value inside the input show with the 2 decimal values in firefox?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places.
It seems that there's no solution.
Solutions like :

    `document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
    });`

don't work either.

Comment: Damn, this seems like a firefox issue that they should address.