# How to allow 1.00 in input field of type='number'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I input 1.12 then it works fine, but if I enter 1 then I want it to display 1.00 in input field.

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#amount', function() {
  var this_val = jQuery(this).val();
  jQuery("#amount").val(parseFloat(this_val).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" step="0.01" min="1">
```

Comment: Seems like it works fine. Whats' wrong with it?

Comment: Run snippet. It's work.

Comment: Use pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076985/format-number-in-an-html5-input-tag

Comment: @Shree If i enter 1.00 then it is converted to 1, i want it to be remain as 1.00

Comment: No repro it's remain 1.00 on snippet.

Comment: @HetalChauhan what is your browser?

Comment: if you use FF, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540491/firefox-how-to-show-number-input-value-with-decimal-spaces?rq=1)

Comment: @AnatoliyR yes i am using firefox, in chrome it works as i want it to be.

Comment: @Shree yes i noticed that it works in chrome

Comment: @HetalChauhan look at the link, seems there is no solution

Comment: var this_val = jQuery(this).val();

if(this_val.indexOf('.') == -1)
{
var setval = parseFloat(this_val).toFixed(2) + '.00';
jQuery("#amount").val(setval);
}
else
{
  jQuery("#amount").val(parseFloat(this_val).toFixed(2));
}

Comment: try as, step="any"

Comment: theoretically you can try some artificial solution, for example start from 0.001 with step 0.01 and add jquery and css to hide last decimal and convert numbers back and force when appropriate... too complicated, so depends how badly you need this fixed

Answer (score 0):

i think this could be a solution..

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="100" value="22.00">
```

This wouldn't show the numeric numbers in float but you can change them later by number_float() function in php