# Input type number with toFixed value failing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a view tht has the following requirements:

- HTML input `type` **must** be `number`
- Programatically set the value of the model attribute of that input with 2 trailing decimals
- Allow for user input to modify that value

Now, seting the value programatically as `1.20` for that value to display in the input is complicated:

- `parseFloat(1.20)` returns `1.2`
- `(1.20).toFixed(2)` returns a string `'1.20'`, for which AngularJS fails when attempting to set the value

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the [`ng-pattern` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) or create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that uses the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5680#issuecomment-206325921 I did the following:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
        .directive('toFixed', [function () {
            return {
                require: '^ngModel',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                        return parseFloat(value);
                    });
                    ngModel.$render = function() {
                        var viewValue = parseFloat(ngModel.$viewValue || 0);
                        element.val(viewValue.toFixed(2));
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of NgModel and add a parser or formatter.

```
function NumberFormatter($filter){
'ngInject';

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
          //format text going to user (model to view)
          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
             return $filter('number')(parseFloat(value) , 2);
          });

          //format text from the user (view to model)
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            return doParsing(value)
          });
    }
}
}
```

[ngModel Formatters and Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841225/ngmodel-formatters-and-parsers)

Comment: When creating custom directives that work with the `ng-model` directive it is best to avoid using isolate scope. Also avoid two-way binding with the `ng-model` attribute; use one-way binding (`<`) for input, `$setViewValue` for output.

Comment: looks like i can remove the isolate scope in this case.

Comment: This solution doesn't address the main issue that formatting the value with `toFixed` fails when rendering to the view, as input type is number, not string (which `toFixed` returns), otherwise I get `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected 1.20 to be a number`

Comment: Could you use a number input step instead of toFixed()? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: I updated the answer to include a number filter which should always display two decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Same old error. `typeof $filter('number')(parseFloat(value) , 2)` = `'string'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173417/discussion-between-monove-and-phil-ninan).