# Input type=[number] converts float to int on display

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, input

I want to display a value of lets say 100.00 in a number input. This can be user entered and works with currency so it is important that it shows.

However when programatically setting the value to 100.00 it resets the displayed variable to 100.

However if you write 100.00 then it works fine. Problem is that there is validation on this input and the value gets refreshed by the javascript putting it back to 100.

Edit: Seems to only be affecting Firefox.
I have tried adding the value as

```
input.value = 100.00

input.value = parseFloat(100.00)

input.value = parseFloat(100.00).toFixed(2).
```

```js
document.getElementById('test_input').value = 100.00;
```

```html
<input id="test_input" type="number" step="0.01">
```

And JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3qnL07yu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Number Input - Always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: `parseFloat(100.00).toFixed(2)` doesn't work ? you can use just `100` and add toFixed(2)

Comment: @MihaiT Doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: well. I don't think there's a way around that when it comes to number inputs :-s

Answer (score 2):

You can update the input value like this:

```
document.getElementById('test_input').value = "100.00";
```

Here is the updated code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zun0aptf/4/

Answer (score 0):

Possible Ways: you could set your values like this

```
 <input id="test_input" type="number" step="0.01" value="100.00">
```

Or

```
 document.getElementById('test_input').value = "100.00";
```

Comment: First solution wouldn't help me if I am setting it in javascript., Second solution works in Chrome. Doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type="number"` to `type="text"` and put validation for number.

```
 <input id="test_input" type="text" step="0.01">
```

Updated code : https://jsfiddle.net/8c6n012f/1/