# How to change input range value from 1.9 to 2.0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have:

```
<input type="range" id="rating-range-btn" name="ratingrange" min="5" value="5" max="10" step="0.1">
```

I need to change input value from 1.9 to 2.0 but it shows only 2 without dot and zero

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: I don't use jQuery

Comment: Is there any way to do this using pure javascript or in html?

Comment: Anything you can do in jQuery you can do in pure HTML. There's no way to force the browser to display the decimal places for whole numbers using just HTML.

Comment: @robinsax *Anything you can do in jQuery you can do in pure HTML.* <-- Uh, no. Maybe you meant anything you can do in JQuery you can do with Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: @robinsax no you can't

Comment: Hahaha woops yes guys I mean JS.

Comment: "I need to change input value from 1.9 to 2.0 but it shows only 2" well as I can see the min attribute is set to 5 so 1.9 and 2 and ... I don't undertand what you are doing, because the range is from 5 to 10 and you are talking about 1.9 and 2.0

Comment: yes i'm talking about 1.9 to 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to trigger a callback function each time the value changes to adjust the value of another element that gets its value from the range because the range value (when a whole number is reached) can't be adjusted.

```js
document.getElementById("rating-range-btn").addEventListener("change", function(e){
  // Force the string value of the range to a number and then force the 
  // number to have a single decimal
  output.textContent = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="rating-range-btn" name="ratingrange" min="5" value="5" max="10" step="0.1">
<div id="output">5.0</div>
```