# How do I display a value as a decimal place in vuejs input field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display a 2000.00 in an input field in vuejs but it strips the .00.

```
<div id="app">
   <input
    class="form-control"
    type="number"
    v-model="solicitorsFees"/>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   solicitorsFees: 2000.00,
  },
})
```

How do I get the input field to display 2000.00?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLxk2uce/)

I can do this with a calculated property. But I need to apply this to multiple input fields.

```
solicitorsFeesDecimal: function(){
  return(this.solicitorsFees.toFixed(2))
},

 

<input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="solicitorsFeesDecimal"/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" :value="(this.solicitorsFees).toFixed(2)"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Number Input - Always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641074/html5-number-input-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @RoboKozo unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate solution is to use a computed property with a custom getter and setter, as well as using the `v-model.number` modifier:

**Template**

```html
<div id="app">
   <input
    class="form-control"
    type="number"
    v-model.number="solicitorsFeesDisplay"/>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    solicitorsFeesDisplay: {
      get: function() {
        return this.solicitorsFees.toFixed(2)
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.solicitorsFees = newValue
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      solicitorsFees: 2000.00
    }
  },
})
```

See a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sinoussi-z41c6?file=/src/App.vue) on CodeSandbox.

Comment: This is a good solution. But what about when there are multiple input fields. I need to create a computed property for each of them?

Comment: Sure, or you can create a custom component that handles this internally.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" :value="(this.solicitorsFees).toFixed(2)"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think it will capture the new value in `this.solicitorFees`.

Answer (score -1):

you should you step in input field:

```
<input type="number" v-model="solicitorsFees" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant documentation for the input element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values

Comment: As you can see here. This makes no difference: https://jsfiddle.net/73ckwb4u/

Comment: it does not show because it is all zero .if it was another number with show that.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `parseFloat` and `toFixed` together to define the number of decimal places you want.

`v-model= parseFloat(solicitorsFees).toFixed(2)`

Also, another suggestion is to make the data object as a function, as in your fiddle you are using an object.

```
data () {
    return {
        solicitorsFees: 2000.00
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't bind `v-model` like that.