# Stackoverflow ques-tion highlight color

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I'm trying to find the color that stackoverflow uses to highlight the background when a question answer link is followed

For example the following
[Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5#19012837)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The colour starts as `#F4A83D` and it then fades to white. The animation is controlled via jQuery which sets the `style` attribute directly. No CSS transition is involved. I determined this by setting a breakpoint on changes to the element's attributes.

Comment: $("div").stop().css("background-color", "#F4A83D")
     .animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 1500);