# how to stop "number_to_currency" method from interpreting commas as decimal places for price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, number-to-currency

In my Ruby on Rails app, I've got a model called **Post** which has a column named "*Price*" in it's database table; this column is decimal type with a precision of 8 and scale of 2.

The form for a new **Post** has a 'text_field' for :price, and in the Post *show* view, I've setup "*Price*" to display this way ->

```
<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@post.price) %>
</p>
```

-My problem: the *Price* only displays correctly if the user inputs the value *WITHOUT* any commas. If the user puts in their desired numerical value with commas included, the *Price* ends up rendering as if they meant to put a decimal; hence making the displayed value too low

(example: If a user puts *67,000* as the value for the *Price* field, it will be saved/displayed as **67.00**).

How could this be fixed so that  even if the user includes commas in their originally typed value for *Price*, it will be displayed correctly...? And inversely, if the user doesn't include commas, a method so that the resulting output to the *Show* view is correctly styled with the commas for thousands/millions places...?

Comment: Have you tried setting `step` attribute to the input, like here?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012837/2399861

Comment: How would I do that to this line: <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %> ?

Comment: I believe this: `<%= f.number_field :price, nil, step: 'any', class: "form-control' %>`, from here (not tested thought): http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag

Comment: It gives me a `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)` error when I replace the line with your suggested one... any idea what that indicates?

Comment: By removing 'nil' from the code, it made the rest of the attributes work! Which is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to users "Ruby Racer" and "Mark H" for leading me down the right path to the solution!

Here is the corrected version of the form for a new **Post**:

```
<%= f.label :price %>
<%= f.number_field :price, step: 'any', class: "form-control" %>
```

This allows the Price to be correctly displayed with two decimal places, and simply won't accept commas from the user as initial input.

Answer (score 0):

If commas in the user's input are causing problems, remove them.

```
<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= number_to_currency(@post.price.remove(",")) %>
</p>
# http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-remove
```

For display, the formatting is controlled by the `locale` argument of `number_to_currency()`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

If your application will be used by users who actually do use the comma as a decimal separator, you'll want to handle that situation, too.

Comment: I just tried your .remove(",") trick with number_to_currency as you wrote it, but I'm receiving an **undefined method `remove' for #<BigDecimal:7fce927d4458,'0.2E2',9(27)>** error, any ideas what that means?

The line in question raising the error is '<%= number_to_currency(@post.price.remove(",")) %>'

Comment: It means that the variable held by `@post.price` is a BigDecimal. I had assumed it was a string. Your problem occurs when the user's input is stored in the `@post`, not when it is displayed. That code converts the text to a BigDecimal. Edit your question and add the code that takes user input and puts it in `@post.price`.