# html5 input[type=number] two decimal points

Tags: javascript, html

G'day

I am wanting to use `input[type=number]` to allow 2 decimal **points** for input of a version number. A version number could be formatted like any one of the following; `2`, `1.4`, `1.0.2`.

There is a similar question that resolves this for one decimal point by setting `step=any`. (Please take note of **point** not meaning the same as **place**)

Will I have to roll my own with javascript..

```
function isVersion( ver ) {
    if(!isNaN( ver ))
        return true
    else
        return !isNaN( ver.replace(/\./g, "") );
} 
console.log( isVersion( '1.3.5' ) );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5 should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this with `input[type=number]`. Version numbers like **1.0.2** are not **mathematically legal**.

However, you can use `input[type=text]` and define a proper regular expression as its `pattern` attribute.

For example this one matches semantic versioning numbers:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d+\.\d+\.\d+">
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer, the pattern I'm using is "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)"