# Input validation in input box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a input box that can only take values between 0 to 100 (float is allowed).
Is there any function that can convert the string value in input box to decimal so that I can compare it?

I have tried parseFloat but if the string="10Hi", parseFloat will still return 10.

Comment: try this, `parseFloat("10")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Comment: Have you tried using regular field validator before parsing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function:

```
parseFloat('12.5')
```

for validation you can use regex:

```
var isValid = (inputStr.match(/^-?\d*(\.\d+)?$/));

if (isValid == null)
    alert('in valid');
else 
    alert('valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) ?

```
isFinite(10)      // true
isFinite('10.1'); // true
isFinite('10Hi')  // false
```

Comment: `isFinite('0x5f') && isFinite('2.3e1') // true`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below condition:

```
var str = "12.5", number;

if(isFinite(str) && str.indexOf(".") == -1)
     number = parseFloat(str);
```

**Updated:**

If you need to get the exact number only then you can simply use like below:

```
var str = "12.5", number;

if(isFinite(str))
     number = +str;
```

So it always returns the finite number including the floating value.

If str is '0x5f', then it return the value as 95 because it also a valid hexadecimal number [check here](http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/95).

Comment: So you'd disallow '10.1'?

Comment: Per OP: "*…float is allowed…*".

Comment: updated the answer, so it supports all the valid number formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".decimal").each(function(){
    var v = $(this).val();

    //pattern: integer or decimal
    var valid = /^\d+$/.test(v) || /^\d+\.\d+$/.test(v);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwf3eumk/

Comment: Doesn't allow `'.12'` or `'12.'`, which are valid decimal floats. Any consideration of leading or trailing whitespace? Also gratuitous use of jQuery: `var v = this.value` is hugely more efficient. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To check that input is a decimal float from 0 to 100 inclusive, a regular expression can be used to exclude strings like `'0x5e'` (which is a valid representation of a number between 0 and 100), then the string can be converted to a number to test the value is within the allowed bounds.

e.g.

```
function testValue(n) {
    var re = /^\s*\d*(\d\.?|\.?\d)\d*\s*$/;
    var num = Number(n)
    return re.test(n) && n >= 0 && n <= 100;
}

['12','12.','.12','12.2','0x5e'].forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v + ' : ' + testValue(v));
});

12 : true
12. : true
.12 : true
12.2 : true
0x5e : false
```