# How can I validate input from 1.00 to 99.99 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mask

I try masking but it not working for this. I need verify that an input value is between `1.00` and `99.99` in float. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yourInput < 100 && yourInput >= 1)
```

if you also want to control the number of decimals you could do this:

```
yourInput = yourInput.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I need it  at runtime user can only enter value in float

Comment: That's quite different from the question: instead of validating, you want to restrict the allowed input. Have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012837/2375207

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function on any event.

```
function abc(){
        var textValue = document.getElementById("text").value;
       if (textValue >= 100 || textValue < 1.00) {
             alert("Please insertAmount between 99.99 and 1.00");
             document.getElementById("text").focus();
             return false;
        }
    }
```