# Angular 2 numeric input

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to create an input that only allows for numbers to be typed in it, the problem is that `this.modelChange.next(value)` doesn't appear to be firing unless I actually type a number.

Because if I type a `0`, then add a letter `0a` the model stays at `0`, and if I then add another digit `0a0` then the model updates and so does the input value since then the model has become `00`.

How can I make sure that an updates happens every time you enter something?

Component:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-number-input',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-number-input/form-number-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-number-input/form-number-input.component.css'],
  inputs: [
    'model',
    'alt',
    'placeholder',
    'name',
    'label'
  ],
  host: {
    '(input)': 'isNum($event.target.value)'
  }
})

export class FormNumberInputComponent {
  @Input() model: number;
  @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  isNum(value) {

    value = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');

    this.modelChange.next(value);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <label attr.for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" alt="{{alt}}" id="{{name}}" class="form-number-input">
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<form-number-input [(model)]="myNumber" label="Number" placeholder="Write a number" alt="Number input"></form-number-input>
```

**EDIT:** I found a solution to the problem, although it feels wrong:

```
isNum(value) {

  this.modelChange.next(value);

  value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

  this.modelChange.next(value);
}
```

By calling the `modelChange` before AND after we manipulate the value both the input and the model gets updated, but WHY does this work?

Comment: do you have plunker for the same? or show us your parent component which contains `form-number-input` tag.

Comment: Why not use [input type=number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) ?

Comment: @EricMartinez Because it clears the input if I type 0a for example and doesn't allow floats. So figured it's best to use string and go from there which I also did in Angular 1 with nice results.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz input type number [allow floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5).

Comment: @EricMartinez Didn't when I tried but maybe something else was wrong, either way it's not what I want.

Comment: @micronyks I'm unable to get a plunkr working, so many angular 2 stuff that needs to be included it seems.. And I'm not great at plunkr.