# how to avoid negative,float,and decimal values in form input using javascript validation?

Tags: javascript

I want to avoid negative values and decimal values in form input, like `1.25`, `4.5` etc using javascript validation.

For negative numbers I am using `type="number"` and `min="0"` in input. But how to handle decimal values?

Any help would be great

Comment: negative, decimal and float? and please share the code. I have a feeling that by decimal you mean floating point numbers?

Comment: @Amresh venugopal For normal form hope need not to share the code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5

Comment: Improve formatting, fixed tags

Comment: @amresh venugopal  how can i restrict if an user enters negative the should not be submitted unless he corrects the input?

Comment: @DeepakJawalkar  does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 support for the in-form validation might not be available across all browsers.

```
if(number !== parseInt(number,10)){
  //detects floating point numbers like 1.3  
} else if (number > -1) {
  // detects negative numbers
}
```