# Numbers which was given in textarea should be greater than 0 and less than 5

Tags: angularjs

I have tried using below code for which the textarea accepts numbers greater than 0 and less than 5, everything is working fine but when comes to decimal it unable to validate. below is my code

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myform">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="minmax" ng-model="number" required="required" maxlength="10" numbers-only/>
 <span ng-show="myform.$error.numbersOnly">Enter the numbers only between 0 to 5 </span>
 </form>
 </body>
```

and here is controller

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
 app.directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {


       if(parseInt(inputValue) <= 5  && parseInt(inputValue) > 0){
         modelCtrl.$setValidity('numbersOnly', true);
         return inputValue;
       } else {
         modelCtrl.$setValidity('numbersOnly', false);
          return modelCtrl.$modelValue;
       }

    });
   }
 };
}); 

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.number = ''
 }
```

and here is my working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rOShiJYCZrXcgMdr951i?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr is working exactly, what you want.

Comment: but if give I value in decimal and then pressing enter then its showing alert.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly read this below discussion, before you workaround this issue

[Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

> Now you need to Set `step="0.01` on your input number field. it will be can take decimal and integer values.

```
<input type="number" name="minmax" ng-model="number" required="required" step="0.01 maxlength="10" numbers-only/>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EuR5sHIu5dVgQr2HzarY?p=preview)

Comment: if I keep type ="text" then its accepting alphabets also

Comment: But the error message showing correct. if you enter anything  the validation will be fire.

Answer (score -2):

Try using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
  if(parseFloat(inputValue) <= 5  && parseFloat(inputValue) > 0){
```

and change 
      `input type="number"` to `input type="text"`

Comment: ParseInt also works good. It's couldn't be a conversion problem

Comment: Try entering 5.1 in his plnkr