# Converting input number to Mysql decimal

Tags: mysql, input, decimal, number-formatting

I'm trying to store decimals taken from `input` in a Mysql decimal (10,2) row. But when I enter `37.50` in the input, Mysql only stores `37.00` It seems to disregard everything after the dot. How can I store decimals?

**this the input**

```
<input class='form-control formBlock' name='payrate' value='' step="0.01" type='number' placeholder="Pay Rate..." required>
```

So far I tried float:

```
$payrate=floatval($_POST['payrate']);
```

Comment: Cool story, bro. Was there a *question*?

Comment: @spencer7593: lol dude I'm laughing so hard right now. I forgot to ask. Sorry I will update.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It's unclear what you are asking. (Was there a question? Or was all that just  intended as a status report?)</strike>

In a numeric context ...

MySQL interprets a "dot" character in a numeric literal as a decimal point.

MySQL interprets a "comma" character as *invalid*. MySQL reads the value from left to right until it hits an invalid character, and takes whatever it has read as the value.

As a demonstration, consider

```
SELECT '123,456.78' + 0     --> 123
SELECT '4t2' + 0            --> 4
```

---

If we need to pass a numeric value into MySQL that contains commas, and we want MySQL to disregard the commas, then we can remove the commas

```
SELECT REPLACE('123,456.78',',','') + 0  -->  123456.78
```

If we want a comma treated as the decimal separator, we can replace it with a dot character

```
SELECT REPLACE('456,78',',','.') + 0  -->  456.78
```

Of course, we could also do that string manipulation and cleanup of the value in the client, before we pass the value to MySQL.

<strike>Not sure if any of that answers the question you asked. Was there a question?</strike>

Comment: I have updated the question. What I meant to say is that the decimals after the dots do not get inserted in the database.

Comment: Ok great for this answer. One thing I dont understand why SELECT? I'm actually trying to do an insert?

Comment: @RickJames: As I understand it, yes, it's independent of locale. In MySQL, the dot character is the decimal separator in a string representation of a numeric value.

Comment: @SebastianFarham: We typically use a SELECT statement to demonstrate  MySQL expressions. The expression would be evaluated in the same way in an INSERT. To answer the question as to why   As why a value being inserted to a column `123.45` gets stored as `123`... we'd really need to examine the code you are using. Is the value being cast to an integer value in the client, before it's sent to MySQL? Is there a BEFORE INSERT trigger that modifies the value? I recommend testing from the mysql command line client, to determine if inserting 37.50 works there.

Comment: @SebastianFarham: I would also add some debug code before the insert, var_dump the SQL text and any bind values, before the query execution, to see what is being sent to MySQL. That should help identify whether the issue is on the MySQL database, or in the client. If we are using a prepared statement with bind placeholders (which is what we should be doing) with mysqli, what is the datatype specified for the bind variable?

Comment: @spencer7593: you hit the head right on the nail... I think it has to do with the bind parameter type being an integer...

Comment: @spencer7593: that's it dude! the problem was the bind parameter type! You can change your answer and I will give you the creds