# Validate input field in HTML5

Tags: html

how can i validate in all type of decimal number Like 1234.1234, 7654.9876543, 1.54, 23.532,23.43 etc in
`html5`?

i write

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" required />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Comment: Thanks for that example