# String Replace with Regex Decimal Validation fails in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, onkeyup, key-events

I tried to restrict the user input with string.replace using Regular expression. But it fails, its not allow to enter any character. Kindly see the following HTML Page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Decimal Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key and on keyup in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" maxlength="9" onkeyup="myFunction(this)">

<script>

function myFunction(text) {
 if(text) {
     text.value = text.value.replace(/^(\d{0,4}\.\d{0,5}|\d{0,9}|\.\d{0,8})/g, '');
 }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to allow only the digits and precision (i.e., **allow only one dot**). If the user input is only a **whole number then the length should be 9** or if the input is only decimal part then allow **maximum 8 precision** or if the mixture then allow `decimal(9,5)` - allow 4 digit and 5 precision.

The above said regular expression fails to validate, allow the char only digits and only one period.

Comment: You are replacing every digit or dot just entered by nothing.

Comment: You might use `text.value.replace(/^(\d*(?:\.\d*)?)|./g, '$1')` but onkeyup does not look good here.

Comment: Could you please assist me how to reverse the condition...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/19011861/372239

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Your regular expression allows the character very first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validation and a replacement are two different tasks, you need to test the field first and after to replace with something eventually. Example:

```
function myFunction(text) {
    if( !/^(\d{0,4}\.\d{0,5}|\d{0,9}|\.\d{0,8})$/.test(text.value) ) {
        text.value = ''; // or an other kind of replacement if you need something
                         // more precise
    }
}
```

Note that you can also rewrite the pattern like this:

```
/^(?!\d*\.\d*\.)[\d.]{0,9}$/
```

To keep characters at the beginning that validate the pattern you can use this replacement:

```
text.value = text.value.replace(/^(\d{0,4}\.\d{0,5}|\d{0,9}|\.\d{0,8}).*/, '$1');
```