# input field should accept number and decimal not minus symbols

Tags: html, css, angular

Input field should allow numbers and decimal not minus symbol

```
<input type="number" pattern="[^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$]*">
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The problem is that you're using type "number". This won't work with your pattern for decimals. I've explained it below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a float input type in HTML(5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done! Used the below code

```
@HostListener('keypress') onkeypress(e) {
    let event = e || window.event;
    let charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    let value : any = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

    if ((event.which != 46 || value.indexOf('.') != -1) 
         && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will works perfectly only one dot and numbers and no minus symbol

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got what your problem is. Please take a look at the section ["Allowing decimal values"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). In order for an input field `type="number"` to work with decimals, you need to change the step attribute.

Does this work as you intended?

```html
First try:
<input type="number" pattern="\d+[.,]?\d+" step="0.001">

Second Try:
<input type="text" pattern="\d+|\d+[.,]\d{1,3}">
```

My suggestion to you is to get rid of the `type=number` attribute. You already set a `pattern` attribute for the input, unless you really want to keep the scrolls for plus or minus one step, I'd set `type="text"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <input type="number" pattern="/^[0-9.,]+$/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for much readable and understandable code then this works perfectly for you:

```js
function checkDecimalDot(e)
 {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
       && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="return checkDecimalDot(event)" >
```

Comment: But can your answer prevent something like: `1234,56.78.91.0..,`? This number: `123.456789` is not working when I try your code snippet, I think it's due to the `type="number"` attribute. I explained it in my answer

Comment: Your answer is totally wrong, And i can input `123.456789` in my above snippet. Don't comment rubbish @flen

Comment: Strange, maybe it's a bug in my Firefox version then, but I get the "red" box after inputting it and bluring out. Just tried it again with `12.3`. If you read the MDN doc I posted you can see that input `type="number"` is not supposed to work for decimals in any browser without the "step" attribute

Comment: thanks ..yeah correct.it is not accepting minus. But as to take one decimal.It is accepting so many dots

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will allow you to add only decimals and numbers without any negative value.

```html
<input type="number" min="0"  step="0.001">
```

Comment: If you need any clarification or any issue, can comment here. Cheers!