# prevent negative numbers but accept decimals? HTML

Tags: html

Is there's a way to prevent negative numbers but accept decimals? I'm using PHP and HTML

```html
<input type="number" min="0" id="Student" name="course[]" value="<?php  echo $_POST['course'][3]; ?>"/></p>
```

Comment: You could use JavaScript to force the submission of any number >=0 and use PHP to just double check the number is >=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code theoretically works. It prevents negative numbers and accepts decimals.

I think what you're really asking is this: [Is there a float input type in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

to which the top answer suggests that you would write:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" name="course[]">
```

The thing that matters the most though is not client-side validation, but server-side validation. In the PHP code that accepts this input, you have to validate that the input is valid as follows:

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['course'][3]) && floatval($_POST['course'][3]) >= 0) {
    // The rest of your code.
}
```

To do this for all the courses, you would most likely write:

```
foreach($_POST['course'] as $k => $v) {
    if(!(is_numeric($v) && floatval($v) >= 0)) {
        echo "Input needs to be a number.";
        break;
    }
    // Process the course $_POST['course'][$k] here.
}
```

The main reason you have to check if it's a number in server-side too is that *someone with certain knowledge about browsers* can just open the browser console and edit the attributes of the input removing the type="number", allowing him to send you virtually any text.

Someone with even more knowledge can send you cURL requests.

Comment: Yessssssss, the problem is SOLVED, thank you <3

Comment: Edited my post to provide an in-depth explanation.

Comment: @Bashayer Nouri, if the answer helped you as much as you say it did, please accept and upvote it.