# Javascript: How to show iOs numberic keyboard with a comma

Tags: javascript, ios, html, input, keyboard

```
<input type="number">
```

This input doesn't let you add comma, which is handy for making ammount inputs.

Is there a way to add comma to the keyboard with javascript, like Revolut app did here?

[image: Here is the example how Revolut app have it:]

Comment: Maybe this can be of help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="number">` in iOS should show a keyboard with numbers and punctuation:

[image: iOS 9 keyboard]

This is the closest you can get to your desired keyboard in HTML.

[See more from Filament Group](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/type-number.html)