# Ask user for amount and user value in a form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input

I'm trying to integrate a payment method called SiamPay on my website but I don't know javascript :(

On SiamPay website they have this instructions:

Copy the following program code to your payment page and 
dynamic generate the Amount show below by yourself

```
<form name="payForm" method="post" action="https://www.siampay.com/b2c2/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="Amount">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="764" >
<input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="remark" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
<input type="hidden" name="payMethod" value="ALL">
</form>
```

Example in jsp:

```
<% 
double amount = qty * unitPrice ;
%>

<form name="payForm" method="post" action="https://www.siampay.com/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= amount %>">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="764" >
<input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="remark" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
</form>
```

I would like to create a field where the user can input an amount to pay in THB (Thai currency) and transport that value to this field:
    < input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= amount %>">.

I think this is relatively easy but because I never user javascript I'm a little confused.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you so much.

Best Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create an extra input field. You have to change the **name=amount** input's **type** to **number** so that it will become visible to the user. Now the user can enter a number of their choice and click the pay button to submit the payment form.

```html
<form name="payForm" method="post" action="https://www.siampay.com/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="" placeholder="Enter amount in THB ">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="76117579">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="76117579">
    <input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="764" >
    <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="remark" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
</form>
```

Comment: Amazing Bhaskar :)
That's exactly that :)
Now how can the number have a decimal value? like 1500.47 THB?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexAfonso Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5     All you have to do is add attribute **step="0.01"** to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<form name="payForm" method="post" action="https://www.siampay.com/eng/payment

/payForm.jsp">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
<input type="hidden" id="amount" value="<%= amount %>">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="76117579">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="764" >
<input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="remark" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
</form>

<button id='cmdSend'>Click me</button> 
<input id='howmuch' type="number" name="amount" value=1000>
```

And the JS:

```
document.getElementById("cmdSend").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cmdSend").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";

    //Get the value the user typed:
    var Value = document.getElementById("howmuch").value;
    console.log(Value);

    //Set the value into the hidden input, can be done in 2 ways:
    document.getElementById("amount").value = Value;
    document.getElementById("amount").setAttribute('value',Value);

    //Check the value got assigned:
    console.log(document.getElementById("amount").value);
}
```

Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/s2ztkn8L/

Comment: notice that i changed the 'name' attribute for 'id'. i realize i also could add it like:  <input type="hidden" name="amount"  id="amount" value="<%= amount %>">

Answer (score 0):

To set value to an element, you can use the document.getElementById().value function. Set the amount data into the Amount variable as shown below.

```
var Amount = 123;
```

Also, modify the input tag for the amount to include the same id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amtId" value="Amount">
```

```js
var Amount = 123;

function setAmountValue() {
  document.getElementById('amtId').value = Amount;
}
```

```html
<form name="payForm" method="post" action="https://www.siampay.com/b2c2/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy" onclick="setAmountValue();">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amtId" value="Amount">
  <input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="76117579">
  <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="76117579">
  <input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="764">
  <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="remark" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
  <input type="hidden" name="payMethod" value="ALL">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
In that case the amount will be always 123, I'm I right?
The idea is ask the user for an amount.

Bhaskar method solve the problem, and I add step="any" in this line <input type="number" name="amount" value="" placeholder="Enter amount in THB "> to accept floating values.

Anyway thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Ohkay, I asumed that the amount will be passed to "Amount" variable through code. I see now that you have mentioned the exact requirement in the question! Thanks for the comment!