# Accepting Decimal values within input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field that currently takes in type=number, however this does not allow for decimal numbers, i do need to allow the user to have decimal input but i cant seem to get it working, would regex possibly be the solution to this problem as i would need some sort of validation.

```
<FormControl fullWidth style={{ width: '50%' }}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="estimatedValue">Estimated Value</InputLabel>
    <Input
        type="number"
        id="estimatedValue"
        startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">£</InputAdornment>}
    />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a float input type in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Answer (score 3):

To achieve expected result, use step with type number for input

Please below link for reference from MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Allowing_decimal_values

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Comment: it doesn't quite seem to work for me, still errors saying by rounding the number down or up

Comment: @PaulWillo96, could you confirm the range of values which you are trying for input field, as you can set max and min values

Comment: any value, however it can be a integer or float, min would be 0 as minus would not be accepted, max could be anything

Comment: @PaulWillo96, https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XLWGyv , as mentioned in docs - You can still manually enter any number but it will be invalid and increase/decrease will not work for invalid number

Comment: are you using regex/ function on that field which seems to rounding it off

Comment: no non at all, every time i try and submit on the form i will receive an error saying that i should round down/up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194771/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-paulwillo96).

Comment: are you trying in Chrome browser?