# Allow only decimal value to the textbox in angular 7

Tags: javascript, regex, angular7, angular-directive

In Angular 7, how can I mask an input field (textbox) such that it accepts only decimal value like (8.15 or 15.25) ?

I have the following HTML input:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" (keypress)="numbersOnly($event)">
```

i have following function numbersOnly which allow only decimal numbers but it should not allow to enter decimal point(.) more than one time like below.

**8.155454 or 8.65.24**

it should allow only 1 decimal points after number like below.

**8.15 or 80.45 or 555.14**

below is my function that accept only decimal value.

```
 numbersOnly(event: any) {
    let charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: You should leverage HTML5's `<input type="number" step="0.01">` https://stackoverflow.com/q/19011861/2191572

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry but it also allow to enter decimal point (.) more than one time, i want to restrict it at the time of input it should allow only one decimal point (.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keypress event to capture the input values and check in the event handler that there is only one decimal point.

I've done this by adding `onkeypress="return slideNumber_keyFilter( event );"` to my input element and then used this function:

```
      <script>
        function slideNumber_keyFilter( event ) {
          return ( ( event.charCode >= 48 ) && ( event.charCode <= 57 ) );
        }
      </script>
```

Which in my case didn't allow for any periods, but you can simply replace the code that check the input and keep track if a period is entered, and disallow another.