# Angular Reactive Form with RxJS store for number input

Tags: angular, rxjs, state, angular-reactive-forms, store

I'm tying to understand how to properly build the RxJS based *Store* approach for handling states in my Angular application. Perhaps I'm missing something very simple.

The example is as follows:

- I have Reactive Form bind to UI elements, where one of them is `<input type="number"/>`;
- I subscribe to `myForm.valueChanges` and update my store when changes occur;
- The store does some work under the hood, maybe calls server API, and finally updates its state;
- In the component, I subscribe to the state updates and do `myForm.patchValue(val, { emitEvent: false})`.

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsn6yu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

So far this schema works fine, except for the number inputs.
The problem is that I can't input numbers such as `0.01`.

I understand what is happening and why:

- user enters `0.`;
- the form emits change event with value `0` (because the input has `type="number"`);
- the store does its job and updates state to `0`;
- finally form value is patched to `0` (effectively removing decimal sign or any trailing zeros).

But I would like to understand how such cases are addressed in real-world application (e.g. in bookkeeping where almost all fields are numbers).

Some ideas I considered so far:

- use input `type="text"` and pattern based validation, but then on mobiles devices full keyboard is shown (instead of numeric);
- use constructions such as `.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(...))` and fire store updates only when "real" numeric changes are done, but it does not work when user wants to correct `0.01` to `0.02` by deleting last digit;
- implement custom logic for numeric fields and keep two values (the number and the visual representation of it), but then the benefit of reactive forms fades out;

I'm sure there is well known solution for such simple use case, but I was not able to properly formulate the query to the Google. :)

Thanks!

P.S. Updating store on button click / form submit is not an option as I'm working on *auto-save* feature for my forms.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5

Comment: you can try "update:'onBlur'": https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#set-the-updateon-property-for-all-controls-in-a-form-group