# I want to store number like 1.5,2.3 ... in laravel-8

Tags: laravel-8

I am doing this in my table

```
$table->float('overs');
```

But It showing this
[image: Show image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a float input type in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it by doing:

```html
<input type="float" name="overs" class="form-control" placeholder="ওভার">
```

Comment: [`float` is not a valid input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). My guess is this works for you only bcs `type="float"` is unrecognised, so it is treated as a plain text input.

Comment: but it`s working well and I am doing also math with this. Do you know any other alternative way?

Comment: I described my guess as to why it works - does typing “abc” work? Yes there’s an alternative, see the duplicate question I linked above.

Comment: abc is not working thanks for helps. Can you help me whith this problem. Please remove ans is not useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106421/how-to-replace-in-laravel-8

Comment: I edited your question to make that input a runnable snippet. Click "run" to see - typing "abc" **does** work, which means that `type=float` is *not* working.  If `type=float` was valid, you would not be able to type anything except a float there.

Comment: If you agree, I suggest deleting your answer, since it is incorrect and will just confuse future visitors who have the same problem who do not read the comments.