# How to replace in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

[image]
You can see I can add numbers by doing CRUD operation in laravel
I have added 1.6 and it shows 1.6
But I want when I add 1.6 it will replace and will show one point six

This is NumberController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }
```

I will add my value here
This is my create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Detail:</strong>
                <input type="double" name="detail" class="form-control" placeholder="Detail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have to show replace value here
This is my index.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->detail }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}" method="POST">

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">Show</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.edit',$product->id) }}">Edit</a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please check update

Comment: where you have added it? Does it mean when you edit and replace with new it gives the same?

Comment: no if i add 2.6 it will show tow point sex .  check update also

Comment: see it https://stackoverflow.com/a/34808724/14527588