# Input field will take only one decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to make field numeric only. Everything going fine, but it allows more than one decimal point.Experts please help..

```
$("#" + fieldId).keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190,110]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
```

Comment: event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 190 if you want decimals. If you don't want decimal remove that.

Comment: I want decimal..But that will be only one..Hope you understand..

Comment: `type="number"` for input.

Comment: my htlm version doesn't support that..

Answer (score 0):

try something like (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796827/jquery-allow-only-two-numbers-after-decimal-point))

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var text = $(this).val();

  if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 1) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
    ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 1)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: please do something in my code..Thanks for the response

Comment: @MakReza your code lacks the check of using decimal only once. If you can create a fiddle I can make changes in your code, else try this one.

Comment: do something here..
if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

Comment: @MakReza this code doesn't check if the decimal is input only once. Please be more precise in your comment.

Comment: @MakReza Yes, but your code doesn't ensure that or even check that.

Comment: @MakReza Can you try the code I have shared? Or else create a fiddle so that I can manipulate your code

Comment: yeah,i have tried the lower half of ur code..but didn't work...:(

Answer (score 0):

```
Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}
```

Ex.

```
var x = 23.453453453;
x.countDecimals(); // 9
```

check count before **event.preventDefault();**

This may help you.

```
$("#" + fieldId).keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190,110]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ($("#" + fieldId).val().countDecimals() >=2  || (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
```

Comment: $("#" + fieldId).val().countDecimals() this will give decimal points. If at any key press this value > or equal to 2 then we prevent that key to write.

Comment: Can you make console.log($("#" + fieldId).val().countDecimals() >=2). and check is it getting true/false after 2 decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

if your happy with your solution and you want just to allow one decimale you will have just add an extra line to check that, I use your code but I change keydown to **keypress** otherwise it wont work to catch the dot character, I added( **||($(this).val().split(".").length - 1 > 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '.')** ) at the end of the code:

-the added code just check whether there is already a dot and if the pressed key is dot.

```
$("#" + fieldId).keypress(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190,110]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ($("#" + fieldId).val().countDecimals() >=2  || (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105 || ($(this).val().split(".").length - 1 > 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '.'))) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
```

- your way of doening it wont prevent a user from pasting a invalid content you you can prevent user from dat with this code:

  ```
    $("#" + fieldId).bind('paste', function (e) 
    {
       e.preventDefault();
    });
  ```
- I would advise you not to validate on kepress or keydown because of:
- user can type a dot after the number and leave the input (like 88. => not valid) which your code wont prevent(and can not otherwise the user can not type a decimale number).
- bij pressing many keys at the same time I was abel to get invalid characters in the input without preventing them.

-I would advise you to validate on blur so that the user get the freedom of editing and you can  be sure of validating the real content of the input.