# Cannot get raw value from (including dot(.)) from HTML input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the input `<input type="number" id="n" />` ; type some key on `keypress` function of the input. Then typing `.` though it display on the input but I cannot get see `.` in `$('#n').val()`.

For example after typing: `123.` Then `$('#n').val()` only return `123`.

Is there any attribute of `<input type="number" />` that I can get its `raw value` which is `123.` rather than `123`?

```js
$("#n").on("keypress", function(event) {
  console.log($("#n").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{1,2}([\.][0-9]{1,2})?" id="n" step="0.01" />
```

[JSbin demo](https://jsbin.com/pazaqarahu/edit?html,js,console,output)

UPDATE:

- `input` MUST have type number to allow it to showing number input only on softkeyboard on mobile web.
- It should check for pattern 99.99 and work as below:

  1. When type 9 OK // input: 9
  2. type 9 OK // input: 99
  3. type 9 NO, it not match pattern // input: 99
  4. Then type 1 NO, it not match pattern // input: 99
  5. ..Free type typing anything rather than dot(.) here...
  6. type dot(.) OK // input: 99.
  7. type 9 OK // input: 99.9
  8. type 9 OK // input: 99.99
  9. type 9 NO // input: 99.99

Without detect the existance dot(.) how can I detect the case of typing multiple `.` consecutively ?

Comment: Use `keyup` event

Comment: @Satpal: `keyup` doesn't work https://jsbin.com/korofateji/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `123.` is `123`, why do you need the period? Doubt you will get it since there is no real way to get the raw value out.

Comment: @epascarello: because I wanna use this info to constraint input number when each time. I.e: only allow 1 number after dot(.) 123.4 - so must detect of the existence of the `.`

Comment: So the . will be there after they add one number. Issue you have is input numbers parses it for you so you have no control. You can listen to key events and see what the value is, but not reading the value.

Comment: Its a XY problem, May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796827/jquery-allow-only-two-numbers-after-decimal-point) can help

Comment: So @o0omycomputero0o your only option is really, not use number input.

Comment: Still not sure why it is a big deal with not having the decimal. Just like how when the user enters in 123.0, you will get out 123 since there are no significant digits. Only way around this would be to use a text input and build the step functionality yourself.

Comment: @epascarello: i've updated the problem :)

Comment: *"typing multiple . consecutively"* Reading the value will not return a number when the input is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've myself faced this issue earlier. Maybe this can help:

```js
$("#n").on("keyup", function(event){
  var val = $('#n').val();
  if(event.keyCode == 190) {
    val+='.';
  }
  console.log(val);
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="n" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only issue would fail in cases of paste, delete key

Comment: Sorry, but how to keep track the dot(.) after editing operation .i.e remove the dot(.) then add again....like @epascarello mentioned above.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o once you've got the dot in place, you can just split the string and check if the length of part after decimal is 2 or not

Comment: @epascarello i'll see

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number"
       min="0"
       max="999"
       step="0.000001"
       pattern="[0-9]{1,2}([\.][0-9]{1,2})?" 
       id="n" />
```

This Should Solve your problem. `Use FocusOut event to capture the value`

Comment: @epascarello : For me its working. Here is the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5444/

I tested in Safari Browser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a value from input with type numeric, when value ends with a dot, you need to use a hacky solution that requires you to listen to 'onKeyUp' event. This behavior is intentional since numeric input should only return valid numbers.

Here is my implementation of described solution:

```js
const resultContainer = document.querySelector("#result");
let value = null;

const updateValue = (event) => {
  const DOT_KEY_CODE = 190;
  const BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE = 8;

  let newValue = event.currentTarget.value;
  if (newValue === "" || newValue === null) {
    if (event.keyCode === DOT_KEY_CODE) {
      newValue = value.toString() + ".";
    } else if (event.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEY_CODE) {
      const valueParts = value.toString().split(".");
      const DECIMAL_PART = 1;
      const decimalPlaces = valueParts.length > 1 ? valueParts[DECIMAL_PART].length : 0;
      const LAST_DECIMAL_PLACE = 1;
      if (decimalPlaces === LAST_DECIMAL_PLACE) {
        const REMOVE_ONE_CHAR = 1;
        newValue = value.toString().substring(0, value.toString().length - REMOVE_ONE_CHAR);
      }
    }
  }

  value = newValue;
  resultContainer.innerHTML = newValue;
};
```

```html
<input type="number" onKeyUp="updateValue(event)" />
<div>Received value: <span id="result"></span></div>
```