# How to disable negative value and allow decimal value to an input type number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder why HTML5 has not yet implemented this simple validation to input number

Here's my snippet. I can't enter. (period) and - (negative)

```js
$('input[type="number"]').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }               
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="refund" class="form-control" >
```

But when I tried to enable keyCode for the period, I can input a lot of period in the text box.

```
$('.allow-decimal').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 190)
        {
            return true;
        }               
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery only allow input float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421639/jquery-only-allow-input-float-number)

Comment: But...the validation *works*. You are allowed to input, say, `1...2` but then it's marked as incorrect when the field loses focus. The jQuery code is irrelevant here.

Comment: not really a duplicate, just uses jquery, but could be boiled down to just html input type number. input type number seems like it should be input type int if you can't use decimals and can't turn off negative values using the min attribute

Comment: @Nate neither of these is true: an input of `4.2` is accepted as valid, an input of `-1` is marked in red as invalid [here is a demo](https://jsbin.com/jisujamujo/edit?html,js,output) - note that there is no JS, just HTML5 in play.

Comment: I think the key here is to check for `isNaN()` and apply your validation accordingly.

Comment: I think you can do it in 2 steps, capture the current value of input say in 'keydown' event, then validate your input's new value on 'keyup', if fail, replaced the input's value by old value

Comment: @vlaz you are correct, I think I misunderstood, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There are something in html you could use..

```
<form>
 Quantity (between 0 and 100): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" step=".01">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you can add more digits in `step` tags to accommodate more floating digits.

Comment: try here : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FV8WQB6PJIM6

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onkeyup="validateInput(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="validateInput(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" />
```

above one is inspired from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910161/3732565) will capture the old value for restore purpose
and then

```
function validateInput(input){
      if(isNaN(input.value)||input.value<0)
      {
        input.value = input.oldvalue;
      }

    }
```

this one should work