# Javascript strict matching and validation regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, floating-point, integer

I have

```js
const int = /^[-+]?[1-9]+/
const float = /[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/

// float return true for 

float.exec(1234)

// int return true for
// it matches only 4848
int.exec(4848.48)
```

How do I match only integers and only floats with the respective regex?

Comment: Like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256061/regular-expression-for-finding-decimal-float-numbers

Comment: `const int = /^[-+]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)$/` and `const float = /^[+-]?\d*\.\d+$/`

Comment: Check this one also, maybe it would be helpful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421639/jquery-only-allow-input-float-number

Answer (score 1):

Add start `^` and end `$` delimiters to your expression that matches integers, so that it cannot match only part of a floating point number (see this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XR9up9/1)):

```
^[-+]?[0-9]+$
```

Please note that your original expression for integers wouldn't match integers with zeros in them.

In the floating point case, do the same and also move the point so that it becomes non optional  (see this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aToheI/1)). To match a literal point, you can also escape it instead of using a character group, so that it's not `.` which would mean "any character":

```
^[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$
```

Note that this will match:

- leading zeros, e.g. `001`, `00.2`
- floats with trailing zeros, e.g. `0.200000000`
- an explicit plus sign, `+123`, `+1.2`, `+.2`
- signed zeros: `-0` and `+0` respectively `+0.0` and `-0.0`

If you don't want leading zeros, you can distinguish that with an *or* (`|`). For integers (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XR9up9/2)):

```
^[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

For floats, you need to make the non-capturing group optional, so that numbers that start with a literal dot are still valid (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aToheI/2)):

```
^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)?\.[0-9]+$
```

If you want to exclude signed zeros, which [depending on who you ask exist or don't exist in math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667577/does-negative-zero-exist), but are assignable in most programming languages, you can move the optional sign into the second condition of the *or*.
For integers (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XR9up9/3)):

```
^(?:0|[-+]?[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

For floats, this is more tricky. If you again move the sign into the second condition of the *or*, you won't match `+0.0` and `-0.0`, but you also won't match signed numbers that start with a literal point or `0.`, so this will not work (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aToheI/4)).

To remedy this, you can wrap the whole thing in another *or* and add a negative lookahead in the second condition to explicitly distinguish between `0.0` and others starting with `0.` (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aToheI/5)):

```
^(?:0\.0*|[+-]?(?:(?!0\.0*$)0|[1-9][0-9]*)?\.[0-9]+)$
```

Finally, if you want to assert that the number does not end with trailing zeros, add an appropriate negative lookbehind `(?<![0-9]0)` at the very end after the line ending `$` (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aToheI/6)):

```
^(?:0\.0*|[+-]?(?:(?!0\.0*$)0|[1-9][0-9]*)?\.[0-9]+)$(?<![0-9]0)
```

Btw, you can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Note that in javascript, the `exec()` call may not match for floating point arguments that evaluate to `0`, because that happens before the evaluation of the `exec()` (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6kf1cs0/1/)):

```js
const float = /^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?\.\d+$/ // floats with no leading zeros

console.log(float.exec(0.0))      // null
console.log(float.exec(0.0000))   // null
console.log(float.exec(+0.0))     // null
console.log(float.exec(-0.0))     // null
console.log(float.exec('0.0'))    // ["0.0"]
console.log(float.exec('0.0000')) // ["0.0000"]
console.log(float.exec('+0.0'))   // ["+0.0"]
console.log(float.exec('-0.0'))   // ["-0.0"]
```